# How to use 3 ionic-slides in one page and take instance of each ion-slides?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-slides

In my Ionic-3 mobile application, **i want to use 3 ion-slides** in one page, and in each **ion-slides** i want to get index of current slide, so that i can use it to save index of current slide. It also works if i get instance of **ion-slides**, so that i can use methods provided by ionic-slides. What should i do to take instance of **ion-slides**?

Comment: @sebaferreras, thanks your solution is working

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)